# How to get current and next datetime record depending on current datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I'm working on a small project which shows tv programs schedule. The main problem is that I need to show 4 programs including current program. The problem is that I really don’t know if the first program from the result is current or may be just the next as previous is still in place...

For example:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | date       | time     |
+----+------------+----------+
| 38 | 2016-11-15 | 11:55:00 |
| 39 | 2016-11-15 | 13:00:00 |
| 40 | 2016-11-15 | 13:30:00 |
| 41 | 2016-11-15 | 14:00:00 |
| 42 | 2016-11-15 | 14:30:00 |
| 43 | 2016-11-15 | 15:00:00 |
| 44 | 2016-11-15 | 15:30:00 |
| 45 | 2016-11-15 | 16:30:00 |
| 46 | 2016-11-15 | 18:30:00 |
| 47 | 2016-11-15 | 19:20:00 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

- Current time is 12:15, so I need to get id: 38, 39, 40, 41
- Current time is 13:33, so I need to get id: 40, 11, 40, 41

So basically I need to get 4 rows, first should be currently showing if exists.

Comment: "I need to get id: 40, 11, 40, 41" - Would you mind to fix that?

Comment: did you try my answer

Answer (score 2):

You haven't been very clear about what time slot belongs to a program, so I am guessing that this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM shows where id >= 
  (SELECT id FROM shows 
   WHERE `time` <= '13:33' AND `date` = '2016-11-15' 
   ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: I think this is correct solution only one correction in `time` <= '13:33'

Comment: I nee to check `curtime >= program_time && curtime < next_program_time`

Comment: I do believe this gives you that without an explicit check for the next show time. It's implicit.

Comment: This will return the current program and 3 last/pervious programs. But OP wants the current program and the 3 next/future programs.

Comment: hi @PaulSpiegel, nopes it returns the next 3, you can create an sql fiddle with the provided data and that will confirm my statement

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry. I was confused by `where \`time\` <= '13:33'`. http://rextester.com/LIZ9451 - Use the `date` to get my vote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward:

```
SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE TIMESTAMP(date, time) >= (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP(date, time)
    FROM shows
    WHERE TIMESTAMP(date, time) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date, time) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date, time)
LIMIT 4
```

Result when current time is `2016-11-15 12:59:59`:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | date       | time     |
+------+------------+----------+
|   38 | 2016-11-15 | 11:55:00 |
|   39 | 2016-11-15 | 13:00:00 |
|   40 | 2016-11-15 | 13:30:00 |
|   41 | 2016-11-15 | 14:00:00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

Result when current time is `2016-11-15 13:00:00`:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | date       | time     |
+------+------------+----------+
|   39 | 2016-11-15 | 13:00:00 |
|   40 | 2016-11-15 | 13:30:00 |
|   41 | 2016-11-15 | 14:00:00 |
|   42 | 2016-11-15 | 14:30:00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

[`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function is used to combine date and time.